# Jackson serialization/deserialization for ZonedDateTime

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson

This is part of my html form.

```
<form th:object="${applyForm}" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" >
    <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right"
                                for="form-field-1"> Start Date </label>

                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="date" id="form-field-1" th:field="*{startDate}"
                                    placeholder="Completion Date- Estimated"
                                    class="col-xs-10 col-sm-7" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right"
                                for="form-field-1"> Completion Date </label>

                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="date" id="form-field-1" th:field="*{completionDate}"
                                    placeholder="Completion Date- Estimated"
                                    class="col-xs-10 col-sm-7" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
</form>
```

I am using Lombak.

```
public class ApplicationForm implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2961891549847290936L;

    @Column(name = "start_date", nullable = false)
    private ZonedDateTime startDate;

    //@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd")
    @Column(name = "completion_date", nullable = false)
   private ZonedDateTime completionDate;

}
```

This is the Error when I try to submit my form. I have tried using @DateTimeFormat but I still cannot get rid of this error. I am using spring and hibernate.

```
Field error in object 'applyForm' on field 'commencementDate': rejected value [2017-11-23]; codes [typeMismatch.applyForm.commencementDate,typeMismatch.commencementDate,typeMismatch.java.time.ZonedDateTime,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [applyForm.commencementDate,commencementDate]; arguments []; default message [commencementDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.ZonedDateTime' for property 'commencementDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.Column java.time.ZonedDateTime] for value '2017-11-23'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2017-11-23]]
Field error in object 'applyForm' on field 'completionDate': rejected value [2017-07-30]; codes [typeMismatch.applyForm.completionDate,typeMismatch.completionDate,typeMismatch.java.time.ZonedDateTime,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [applyForm.completionDate,completionDate]; arguments []; default message [completionDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.ZonedDateTime' for property 'completionDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@javax.persistence.Column java.time.ZonedDateTime] for value '2017-07-30'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2017-07-30]]
```

Comment: Just use the appropriate type: you're asking a date (year + month + day) to your user. Not a nanosecond-precise instant with a timezone. So use a LocalDate, not a ZonedDateTime.

Comment: Same error despite me changing to LocalDate. The error is gone when I change it to Date. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the jackson module for serializing/deserializing Java 8 date/time types so that you can configure you jackson message converter to automatically take care the serialization and deserialization of Java 8 data types.

Maven dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then in your spring config, configure `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to use an `ObjectMapper` that registers the new module.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    // ... Other configs

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(mapper);

        return converter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters( List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters ) {
        converters.add(converter());
    }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) is the README.md for the Jackson Java 8 data type modules